# Как создавать несколько таймеров в pygame

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame, таймер

Я создаю свою первую игру "Змейка". Для этого выбрал библиотеку pygame. Сейчас сильно туплю над тем. как создать несколько таймеров: один для появления бонусного яблака, другой для его исчезновения.
`pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 10000)  # таймер появления яблока`
`pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 100000)  # таймер появления удаления яблока`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"яблоко поместили на экран"
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 10000)
```

В обработчике событий:

```
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.USEREVENT: 
            if 'картинка на экране':
                "картинку убираете"
                pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 100000)
            else:
                "картинку на экран"
                pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 10000)
```

Из документации:

> Также стоит отметить, что определенный тип события можно поставить на таймер только один раз. Другими словами, не может быть двух таймеров для одного и того же типа события. Установка таймера события для определенного события отменяет старый таймер для этого типа события.
> https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer

Comment: Сергей Кох, спасибо вам большое